# Rename column headers in pandas by concatenating with previous header name

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a set of column names where the name Description exists multiple times.

```
['Sl.No', 'Job', 'Description', 'Vendor', 'Description', 'WO No',
       'Accounting Center ', 'Description', 'Nature Of Work', 'WO Type',
       'WO Date', 'WO From Date', 'WO To Date', 'Bill No', 'Running Bill No',
       'Bill Date', 'Bill Status', 'Voucher No', 'Voucher Date',
       'Bank \nVoucher No', 'Bank Voucher\n Date', ' Paid Amount', 'Currency',
       'WO Amt', 'Bill Amt', 'Service Tax Amt', 'VAT Amt', 'Total Tax \nAmt',
       ' Advance Amt', 'Gross Amt', 'Deduction Amt', 'Net Amt']
```

I want the name "Description" to be concatenated with whatever header name is exactly behind it

e.g.

- 'Job', 'Description'  will become 'Job_Description'
- 'Vendor', 'Description' will become 'Vendor_Description' and so on

I need a logic that does not introduce any hard-coding

```
['Sl.No', 'Job', 'Job_Description', 'Vendor', 'Vendor_Description',....]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify where `Description` is present using [`pd.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then use [`pd.Index.to_series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html), so that we can use [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html).

```
cols = df.columns.to_series()
m = cols.eq('Description') #would mark True where value is `Description`
out = cols.shift().str.strip().str.replace('\s+','_') + '_' + cols
out[~m] = cols
out.to_list()

['Sl.No', 'Job', 'Job_Description', 'Vendor', 'Vendor_Description', 'WO No',
 'Accounting Center ', 'Accounting_Center_Description', 'Nature Of Work',
 'WO Type', 'WO Date', 'WO From Date', 'WO To Date', 'Bill No', 'Running Bill No',
 'Bill Date', 'Bill Status', 'Voucher No', 'Voucher Date', 'Bank \nVoucher No',
 'Bank Voucher\n Date', ' Paid Amount', 'Currency', 'WO Amt', 'Bill Amt',
 'Service Tax Amt', 'VAT Amt', 'Total Tax \nAmt', ' Advance Amt', 'Gross Amt',
 'Deduction Amt', 'Net Amt']
```

Comment: you are replacing "Job" field , i intend to keep it, as in 'Sl.No', 'Job','Job_Description','Vendor', 'Vendor_Description'

Answer (score 0):

If it is a dataframe, then you can not assign the concatenated column names back to the dataframe without processing the underlying column data itself. Otherwise, you may get ***"ValueError: Length mismatch"*** error.

If it is just a list of values and you want to concatenate the value "Description" to its previous element, then the following code may help.

```py
colList = ['Sl.No', 'Job', 'Description', 'Vendor', 'Description', 'WO No',
       'Accounting Center ', 'Description', 'Nature Of Work', 'WO Type',
       'WO Date', 'WO From Date', 'WO To Date', 'Bill No', 'Running Bill No',
       'Bill Date', 'Bill Status', 'Voucher No', 'Voucher Date',
       'Bank \nVoucher No', 'Bank Voucher\n Date', ' Paid Amount', 'Currency',
       'WO Amt', 'Bill Amt', 'Service Tax Amt', 'VAT Amt', 'Total Tax \nAmt',
       ' Advance Amt', 'Gross Amt', 'Deduction Amt', 'Net Amt']

colList = [i.replace('\n','').strip() for i in colList] #removing newline and trailing spaces
desc_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(colList) if x == "Description"]
pre_desc_indices = [i-1 for i in desc_indices]

newColList = []
for i, x in enumerate(colList):
    if i in pre_desc_indices:
        newColList.append(x.replace(' ','_')+'_'+colList[i+1])
    elif i in desc_indices:
        continue
    else:
        newColList.append(x.replace(' ','_'))

print(colList)
print(newColList)
```

Comment: actually i do not intend to replace the column name, i have edited the question to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Let `cols` be the name for your original list. Then the code may be:

```
D = "Description"

previous_current = zip([None] + cols[:-1], cols)
df.columns = [curr if curr != D else prev + "_" + D  for prev, curr in previous_current]
```

---

*The result:*

```
>>> df.columns
```

> ```
> Index(['Sl.No', 'Job', 'Job_Description', 'Vendor', 'Vendor_Description',
>        'WO No', 'Accounting Center ', 'Accounting Center _Description',
>        'Nature Of Work', 'WO Type', 'WO Date', 'WO From Date', 'WO To Date',
>        'Bill No', 'Running Bill No', 'Bill Date', 'Bill Status', 'Voucher No',
>        'Voucher Date', 'Bank \nVoucher No', 'Bank Voucher\n Date',
>        ' Paid Amount', 'Currency', 'WO Amt', 'Bill Amt', 'Service Tax Amt',
>        'VAT Amt', 'Total Tax \nAmt', ' Advance Amt', 'Gross Amt',
>        'Deduction Amt', 'Net Amt'],
>       dtype='object')
> ```

---

*The explanation:*

We constructed something as list of pairs `(previous, current)`:

```
>>> previous_current = zip([None] + cols[:-1], cols)
>>> list(previous_current)
```

> ```
> [(None, 'Sl.No'),
>  ('Sl.No', 'Job'),
>  ('Job', 'Description'),
>  ('Description', 'Vendor'),
>  ('Vendor', 'Description'),
>  ('Description', 'WO No'),
>  ('WO No', 'Accounting Center '),
>  ('Accounting Center ', 'Description'),
>  ('Description', 'Nature Of Work'),
>  ('Nature Of Work', 'WO Type'),
>  ('WO Type', 'WO Date'),
>  ('WO Date', 'WO From Date'),
>  ('WO From Date', 'WO To Date'),
>  ('WO To Date', 'Bill No'),
>  ('Bill No', 'Running Bill No'),
>  ('Running Bill No', 'Bill Date'),
>  ('Bill Date', 'Bill Status'),
>  ('Bill Status', 'Voucher No'),
>  ('Voucher No', 'Voucher Date'),
>  ('Voucher Date', 'Bank \nVoucher No'),
>  ('Bank \nVoucher No', 'Bank Voucher\n Date'),
>  ('Bank Voucher\n Date', ' Paid Amount'),
>  (' Paid Amount', 'Currency'),
>  ('Currency', 'WO Amt'),
>  ('WO Amt', 'Bill Amt'),
>  ('Bill Amt', 'Service Tax Amt'),
>  ('Service Tax Amt', 'VAT Amt'),
>  ('VAT Amt', 'Total Tax \nAmt'),
>  ('Total Tax \nAmt', ' Advance Amt'),
>  (' Advance Amt', 'Gross Amt'),
>  ('Gross Amt', 'Deduction Amt'),
>  ('Deduction Amt', 'Net Amt')]
> ```

Then we iterated it and by the 2<sup>nd</sup> element of the pair (the *current* column label) we decided

- whether to **keep it untouched**, or
- **append it** to the *previous* column's label (the 1<sup>st</sup> element of the pair).

Comment: @DKM, *what* it explains? *What* answer? (The sorting order of answer is not fixed.)

Comment: please refer to the answer by Ch3steR , it solved my query

Comment: @DKM — *“please refer to the answer by Ch3steR , it solved my query”*. Do you think, that my answer didn't solve it? Please, be more specific. IMHO my solution is more elegant.

Comment: your answer also solved the issue , both are correct but i can mark only one as correct

Comment: @DKM, you may *voting up* (click on the upper triangle) *so many answers, as you want*. In contrast, you may *accept* (click on the checkmark) only *one* answer, but you may change your opinion every time by accepting the other answer. So, please, consider to upvote other correct answers, too.